# Use AWSMobileClient without `awsconfiguration.json`in iOS

Tags: ios, aws-amplify

I'd like to authenticate an iOS device to use AppSync/S3 services via Cognito user pools. The [AWSMobileClient](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/authentication) provides some nice conveniences but [the initialization](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/blob/016f648abf3d5bbd2e4378dc33d6782594f5ee3c/AWSAuthSDK/Sources/AWSMobileClient/AWSMobileClient.swift#L172) requires that you're bundle have an `awsconfiguration.json` file -- which our application will define dynamically. Is there a way to configure that manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of AWS iOS SDK [2.11.0](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/releases/tag/2.11.0) (9th September 2019) it is now possible to configure without an `awsconfiguration.json` file.

It's even documented in the amplify documentation [here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/manualsetup#configure-using-an-in-memory-object)

See also my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56771885/how-to-setup-different-configurationawsconfiguration-json-with-awsmobileclient/58184476#58184476) to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56771885/how-to-setup-different-configurationawsconfiguration-json-with-awsmobileclient/58184476#58184476)

Comment: For anyone looking for android, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56771885/how-to-setup-different-configurationawsconfiguration-json-with-awsmobileclient/58184476#answer-63284523.

Comment: Anything specifically for flutter?

Answer (score 8):

The current solution is to use the multi-environment workflow from the CLI. 
https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/multienv?sdk=ios

---

Edit

If the multi-environment workflow from the Amplify team doesn't work for you, what you can do is create debug and prod versions of your config, and then create a build phase that copies the correct one based on your build settings (debug vs release, etc).  This is working extremely well for one of my projects.

[image: Config files]

[image: Build phases]

```
#export; #Prints list of all xcode variables with values
printf "$CONFIGURATION\n";

if [ "$CONFIGURATION" = "Debug" ]; then
printf "creating debug configuration";
cp -r "$PROJECT_DIR/awsconfiguration-debug.json" "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$PRODUCT_NAME.app/awsconfiguration.json"
else 
printf "creating production configuration";
cp -r "$PROJECT_DIR/awsconfiguration-prod.json" "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$PRODUCT_NAME.app/awsconfiguration.json"
fi
```

Comment: Ah, bummer as close as we can get right now I suppose! Thanks for posting, I'll accept this answer -- for my particular use-case, I am going to configure services via QR code at runtime so still looking for another solution. Thanks again!

Comment: I agree.  I'd much rather specify it via code like the JS SDK allows you to do.

Comment: @tgk check out the edit above, it may work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a specific solution:

```
extension AWSMobileClient {
    convenience init?(configuration url: URL) {
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else { return nil }
        guard let dict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any] else { return nil }

        self.init(configuration: dict)
    }

    convenience init?(configuration name: String) {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "json") else {
            return nil
        }

        print("INITIALIZING AWSMobileClient [\(name)]")
        self.init(configuration: url)
    }
}
```

To use it, you can have as many different awsconfiguration-XXX.json files as you need, and at runtime you initialize with the one you want by:

```
let mobileClient = AWSMobileClient(configuration: "awsconfiguration-XXX")
mobileClient.initialize { (userState, error) in ... }
```